# after delete of item in SwiftUI List (backed by Core Data) getting a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error? (code attached)

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

After completing a delete of a row in a SwiftUI List I am getting a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error.  It seems the Core Data delete works as after I restart that data has been removed.  So maybe something to do with SwiftUI trying to update it's view after the Core Data delete is performed????

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: GCItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var gcItems: FetchedResults<GCItem>

    private func addItem(title:String) {
        let newItem = GCItem(context: context)
        newItem.id = UUID()
        newItem.title = title
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let e as NSError {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(e), \(e.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    private func deleteItem(at offsets:IndexSet) {
        self.context.perform {
            // Delete Item
            for index in offsets {
                let item = self.gcItems[index]
                self.context.delete(item)
            }

            // Persist
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            } catch let e as NSError {
                // TODO: How to undelete list???
                print("ERROR : Can not save GCItem items: \(e.description)")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List() {
                    ForEach(gcItems) { gcItem in
                        HStack {
                            Text("test")
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
                }
                Button(action: { self.addItem(title: "Testing 123") }) {
                    Text("ADD ITEM")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
#endif
```

Screen Shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was NOT to use attributes in Core Data named "id".  So I changed this to "myId" and then things worked fine.

Comment: I was becoming crazy about this problem myself. Just curious, how did you find out?

Comment: Just a guess/try and see